# Onchange Javascript to update input field on VF page When an item is selected on Selected list

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript

I created a VF page with input fields of Account Object.
I created a select list on Vf page using controller. 
I want to update the input field(`selected__c` : `datatype--text`)  with selected option in select list.

So My question is how to write java script to make it work ?

Comment: You can do this in a few ways, paste some code so we get an idea of what you would like to do :)

Answer (score 1):

We can do this using two different approach :

1. Using Actionfunction of VF and then rerender the outputPanel containing our text field
   https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000096tTIAQ
2. using Javascript to input the text in text input 
   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/get-selected-value-in-dropdown-list-using-javascript